# image in html not displaying properly in page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html image, which should fit in the screen properly. My html code is like below:

```html
  <div  class="page">

        <!-- preloader start -->
        <div id="preloader">
          <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- preloader end -->

        <!--header start-->
        <header id="masthead"   class="header ttm-header-style-classic-overlay">
            <!-- ttm-header-wrap -->
            <div class="ttm-header-wrap">
                <!-- ttm-stickable-header-w -->
                <div id="ttm-stickable-header-w" class="ttm-stickable-header-w clearfix">
                    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
                        <div class="site-header-menu-inner ttm-stickable-header">
                            <div class="container">
                                <!-- site-branding -->
                                <div class="site-branding">
                                    <a class="home-link" href="index.html" title="Planwey" rel="home">
                                        <img id="logo-img" class="img-center" width="260" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="logo-img">
                                    </a>
                                </div><!-- site-branding end -->
                                <!-- header-icins -->

                                <!--site-navigation -->
                                <div id="site-navigation" class="site-navigation">
                                    <div class="ttm-menu-toggle">

                                    </div>
                                    <nav id="menu" class="menu">
                                        <ul class="dropdown">
                                            <li  class="active"><a style="font-size:25px;" href="index.html">Telangana Event Industry Association</a>

                                            </li>
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
&nbsp
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
                                            &nbsp
<li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>
                                </div><!-- site-navigation end-->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--ttm-header-wrap end -->
            <!--rev-slider -->

            <!--rev-slider end-->
        </header>

        <div>
          <img src="8.07.2019_new.jpg">
        </div>
        <!--header end-->

        <!--site-main start-->



</div><!-- page end -->
```

so after the header nav menu, the image will display, but the problem is the image is not fitting correctly in the screen, some of its contents are hiding and displaying only the middle part of the image. can anyone please tell me how to fit the image correctly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the snippet you've provided, this sounds like a CSS issue.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa is there any way for an inline style to make it force fit to the screen?

Comment: It's pretty normal to use `.img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }` however I'm blindly guessing as to your problem since your example doesn't actually reproduce any issues that I can see.

Comment: @TEIA2019 what about if image has small resolution ?

Comment: can you please be elaborate about how you want it to look the image you provided loads fine i gues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear enough to answer. If you want your image to work as a background for your header you should make it as a background image in your CSS.

```
header {
 background: url();
}
```

But if you want to make it fill your navigation bar, it's better to make its height and width 100% of its container.
maybe you can explain more so I can help you through this.